# angular, requirejs custom directive

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I am working with Angular and Requirejs, and I want to bind a click event on element click which has the **directive** name like this, but my event is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
    app.register.directive('democlick', function () {
        return {
            template: '<div> This is a test </div>',
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                alert('hello world');
            }
        };
    }); 
});
```

I added the directive as a dependency in the controller.

```
define(['app','dataSourceDirectives'], 
    function (app) {
        app.register.controller('data-source.connectionController', ['$scope', 
            function ($scope) {
                $scope.initializeController = function () {
            }
    }]); 
});
```

Comment: I think it's not possible to add directive on-the-go. You should load the directive file intially and need to add the directive as dependency in angular config.

Comment: thank you i have done with this by adding directive file in main.js and then i add dependency in controller now its working :)